# rails : rake db:create is not creating the new table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations, dbmigrate

I am working on an existing rails project where I have to add a new tab. Well, I have written all the corresponding models, views and controllers and then changed the schema.rb file to create the new table.

```
 create_table "ryan_indices", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
  end



create_table "benchmark_indices", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
      end
```

This is my partial schema.rb file. The first table was there before. I am just trying to add  a similar new table for which I created model, view and controller and also added those create_table statements in schema.rb file. But, when I run `rake db:migrate` it does not create the new table. And the `schema.rb file goes back to previous state` I mean my changes  go away after I run `rake db:migrate` command and it shows nothing on the command line screen.

I don't know what I am missing. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To edit [schema.rb is considered to be bad practice](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you):

> ...not designed to be edited, they just represent the current state of the database.

For creating a new model (and thus a new db table) call the rails model generator

```
rails generate model Product name:string
```

Or: For new fields for an existing model please [generate a migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration)...

```
rails generate migration AddNameToProducts
```

... edit it and then run it with "`rake db:migrate`"

These tasks are very well described at the official [RailsGuides > Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)